# Пронумеровать сессии в MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, сессия

Есть исходная таблица:

[image: Исходная Таблица 1]

`user_id` - пользователь, `project_id` - проект, `event_time` - время события.

**Задача**.
Необходимо пронумеровать сессии, при условии, что один пользователь на разных проектах - разные пользователи. За окончание сессии считать отсутствие активности пользователя более 45 минут. Нумерацию сессий начать с 1. Вывести колонку напротив каждого события с указанием номера сессии к которой это событие относится.

**В итоге должна получиться такая таблица**:

[image: Итоговая таблица]

У меня уже есть наброски в виде:

[image: Промежуточный этап]

Был написан такой код:

```
    with user_events_id as (SELECT  user_id,
        project_id,
        event_time,
        concat(user_id, "_", project_id) as id
from user_events), 

session_marker as (select *,
timediff(event_time, previous_time) as diff_time,
case when timediff(event_time, previous_time) is null then 'old' 
when  timediff(event_time, previous_time)<'00:45:00' then 'old' 
else 'new' end as new_old_session
from (select *, LAG (event_time) over ( partition by id order by id, event_time ) as previous_time
from user_events_id) as a
)

select *,
CASE
        WHEN diff_time > '00:45:00' THEN @session_num := @session_num + 1
        ELSE @session_num
    END 
      AS session_number
FROM
    session_marker,
    (SELECT @session_num := 1) AS session_counter
ORDER BY
    id, event_time
```

В колонке `session_number` нумерация, которую удалось сделать, но она не учитывает разных пользователей.

Необходимо чтобы **для каждого нового идентификатора (`user`+`project`) нумерация начиналась снова с 1**.

Результат, который должен выйти, находится на "Итоговой таблице".

Спасибо!

Comment: Ну тривиальная же в общем задача. Для каждой записи получить лаг по времени в партиции по юзеру и проекту, и для каждой группы считать сумму с накоплением для результата проверки, что разность времени более 45 минут.

Comment: По итоговой таблице получается, что сессии считаются для пользователя (user_id), не важно в каком проекте есть активность. Тогда партиции по проекту не нужны. Считаем только активность пользователя. Project_id можно убрать из подсчетов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Идея достаточно простая и часто применяется. Посчитать количество разрывов (>45 мин) нарастающим итогом - это и будет номер сессии.
Пример:

```
select * 
  ,sum(case when dif>45 then 1 else 0 end)
     over(partition by user_id order by eventtime)+1 session_number 
from(
   select *
     ,timestampdiff(minute,lag(eventtime,1,eventtime)
                           over(partition by user_id order by eventtime)
               ,eventtime) dif
   from test
  ) t
```

Получится так

| user_id | project_id | eventtime | dif | session_number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2019-12-01 00:00:00.000 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 2019-12-01 00:01:00.000 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 2019-12-01 00:10:41.000 | 9 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 2019-12-01 00:15:33.000 | 5 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 2019-12-01 00:46:00.000 | 31 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 2019-12-01 10:05:00.000 | 559 | 2 |
| 1 | 1 | 2019-12-01 10:35:00.000 | 30 | 2 |
| 1 | 1 | 2019-12-01 15:00:00.000 | 265 | 3 |
| 2 | 1 | 2019-12-01 15:00:00.000 | 0 | 1 |